# why is the python GUI interface fleeting

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, vim, wxpython

```
#coding=utf-8
import wx 
class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame=wx.Frame(parent=None,title='Bare')
        frame.Show()
        return Ture
app=App()
app.MainLoop()
```

runs OK! but the GUI interface is fleeting, just leaving the CMD console in the screen.
a newer for python ,why the outcome of the GUI interface fleeting? 
environment:Gvim+WIN7+PYTHON2.7

Comment: Maybe it breaks on a `NameError` when it doesn't find `Ture` defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

First, according to `help :!` command of `vim`:

> `:!{cmd}`         Execute {cmd} with **the shell**.

`vim` cause the cmd shell to be executed.

Second, according to [Using Python on Windows - Executing scripts](http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts):

> Python scripts (files with the extension .py) will be executed by
>   `python.exe by` default. **This executable opens a terminal, which stays
>   open even if the program uses a GUI.** If you do not want this to
>   happen, use the extension `.pyw` which will cause the script to be
>   executed by `pythonw.exe` by default (both executables are located in
>   the top-level of your Python installation directory). This suppresses
>   the terminal window on startup.

So, if you want run the GUI program without cmd console, run the program outside the vim using `pythonw.exe`. For instance, save the file with `.pyw` extension, and double click the file.

Answer (score 0):

It is fleeting because you have a NameError in your code. You should be returning True, not Ture, which is undefined.

I am surprised you still see the console window though. If that stays up though, it should be showing the traceback.